# Vuejs reset fields after POST success callback

Tags: firebase, vue.js, vue-resource

I'm having some problems resetting a textarea field after a POST request.
This is my component code

```
<template lang="pug">
    .col-sm-12
        h2 Add new Task
        hr
        .form-group
            textarea.form-control(v-model="task.taskContent")
        .form-group
            button.btn.btn-primary(@click="createNewTask") Add Task
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            task: {
                taskContent: ''
            }
        };
    },
    methods: {
        createNewTask() {
            if (this.task.taskContent.length > 0) {                              

                // Sending data to the server
                this.$http.post('https://vue-taskmanager.firebaseio.com/task.json', this.task)
                .then(response => {
                    console.log(response);                    
                    // Adding the new task to the main template list
                    this.$emit('taskWasCreated', this.task);
                    // Resetting textarea content
                    this.task.taskContent = '';  
                }, error => {
                    console.log(error);
                });                

            } else {
                alert("Sorry you can't create an empty task");
            }

        }
    }
}
</script>
```

This is the parent component

```
<template lang="pug">           
    .container
        .row
            app-newtask(@taskWasCreated="addTask")
            app-taskswrapper(:tasks="tasksArr")
            app-footer

</template>


<script>
import { EventBus } from './main.js';
import UserRegistration from './components/user/UserRegistration.vue';
import TasksWrapper from './components/TasksWrapper.vue';
import NewTask from './components/NewTask.vue';
import Footer from './components/Footer.vue';
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            tasksArr: [
                'Just something to see'
            ]
        };
    },
    methods: {
        addTask(task) {
            this.tasksArr.push(task)
        }
    },
    // Listening on Events from Task.vue 
    created() {
        // Delete task from array
        EventBus.$on('taskWasDeleted', (taskIndex) => {
            this.tasksArr.splice(taskIndex, 1);
            // Delete task from db
            this.$http.delete('https://vue-taskmanager.firebaseio.com/task.json', this.task)
                .then(response => {
                        console.log(response);
                    }, error => {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
        });
        // Fetch tasks from db
        this.$http.get('https://vue-taskmanager.firebaseio.com/task.json')
            .then(response => {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then(task => {
                const resultsArray = [];
                for (let key in task) {
                    resultsArray.push(task[key]);
                }
                this.tasksArr = resultsArray;
            });      
    },
    components: {
        'app-taskswrapper': TasksWrapper,
        'app-newtask': NewTask,
        'app-footer': Footer,
        'app-userregistration': UserRegistration
    }

}
</script>
```

As you can see inside the response callback function I reset the task.taskContent value but the problem is that the string is sent to the db without problems while is not updated in the root component where I have an array storing all these strings.
I was thinking about using a watcher but I don't know if it's a good solution, do you have any suggestions?
Link to the github repo https://github.com/Polenj86/vue-taskmanager

Comment: It's hard to tell what's wrong without seeing your parent component. What code is running on the parent when `taskWasCreated` is emitted? Are you just storing `task.taskContent` or are you storing the whole `task` object in the parent array?

Comment: @MarkM hi, I edited the question and linked a repo if you want to check it all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's clear what is happening now that you've posted your parent component.

You are storing the `task` object in the parent's array. This is not going to be a copy of the task, it's going to be a reference of the same task that you are about to clear. So when you later set `this.task.taskContent = ''` you are changing the task in the parent array too.

Consider this:

```
var task_holder_array = []
var task = {name: "mark"}
task_holder_array.push(task)

console.log("array before: ", task_holder_array)

task.name = ""

console.log("array after: ", task_holder_array)
```

You need to somehow create a new task object to push into the parent's array. There are a lot of ways you could do this. For example:

```
this.$emit('taskWasCreated', {name: this.task.name});
```

Or you could just pass the task name string to the parent and let the parent create the object.